# How do I call the top right to bottom left of a matrix?

Tags: matlab

I know that using `diag(mat`), you can call out the list from top left to bottom right value of the matrix. but how do I call out the top right to bottom left values of the matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with

```
diag(fliplr(mat));
```

`fliplr` does exactly what it says on the tin, and flips the matrix from left-to-right, so that the top-left becomes the top-right, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the matrix is square, you can also do this directly via [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511):

```
n = size(mat,1);
d2 = mat((n:-1:1)*(n-1)+1).'
```

This might be faster in some cases (`diag` by itself is usually faster than linear indexing). This method can probably be adapted to non-square matrices as well. I'd still stick with @MrAzzaman's solution myself, as it's much more readable and almost certainly fast enough in almost all cases.